# Playing a video in UIView( subview )

Tags: iphone, video, subview, mpmoviewcontroller

Is it possible to play the video in uiview's subview (popup) on the same screen only not by using the iPhone video player which player the video in full screen mode.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Insert a HTML5 `video` tag into `UIWebView`, then subview it into `UIView`. I can guarantee that it works for Youtube videos.